# How to collect all deference in rows between two periods?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to see the difference between the two periods for a column.
For example, we see that sales decreased at the end of the month, and we need to see which products were not sold at the end of the month?

I can create SELECT to see quantity for each product for each period:

```
SELECT product_id, count(product_id) AS Count
FROM testDB
WHERE 
    sales_date IS NOT NULL 
    AND  
    delivery_date BETWEEN '2021-02-01 00:00:03.0000000' AND '2021-02-14 23:56:00.0000000' 
GROUP BY 
    product_id
```

and the same SELECT with another period:

```
delivery_date BETWEEN '2021-02-14 00:00:03.0000000' AND '2021-02-28 23:56:00.0000000'
```

So, after these queries I see list for first period with 10 products with quantity and in second period I see list with 7 products with quantity.  I can't get the difference between the lists of the two SELECTs. I tried to use `!=` and `NOT IN` but without any results.

I will be very grateful for your help. Thanks

Sorry for the confusion. I meant the difference between the two selects:

The result of the first one (for first period):

```
Product_ID   Count
grapes.      100
lime.        13
lemon.       15
cherry.      222
blueberry.   123
banana.      1
apple.       123
watermelon   56
```

and second one (for second period):

```
Product_ID   Count
grapes.      10
lime.        1
lemon.       10
cherry.      2
blueberry.   13
banana.      12
```

and I wand to see difference between these selects:

```
Product_ID   Count
apple.       0
watermelon.  0
```

So we did not sell any `apples` and `watermelons` in second period.

Comment: Some sample data, in a **consumable** format, and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: What do you mean by "difference"? The difference of the total count or the difference of whatever for each product?

Comment: [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might be a start. Are the _deference_ counts always `0`?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT product_id, count(product_id) AS Count,delivery_date-sales_date as DIFFERENCE
FROM testDB
WHERE 
    sales_date IS NOT NULL 
    AND  
    delivery_date BETWEEN '2021-02-01 00:00:03.0000000' AND '2021-02-14 23:56:00.0000000' 
GROUP BY 
    product_id
```

This should work for getting the difference between the 2 period columns.